# Why is the ACK flag in a tcpdump represented as a period "." instead of an "A"?

Tags: tcpdump

This is the output of the three way handshake of a TCP connection:

```
23:40:36.011400 IP 10.1.1.11.44733 > 73.5.9.44.80: Flags [S], seq 106492654, win 64240, optio0
23:40:36.013994 IP 73.5.9.44.80 > 10.1.1.11.44733: Flags [S.], seq 712839050, ack 106492655, 0
23:40:36.014026 IP 10.1.1.11.44733 > 73.5.9.44.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 502, options [nop,no0
```

Inside the brackets are the flags for each packet: `[S]` `[S.]` `[.]`

The [man page for tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) describes these values:

> The general format of a TCP protocol line is:
>
> src > dst: Flags **[tcpflags]**, seq data-seqno, ack ackno, win window,
>   urg urgent, options [opts], length len
>
> Src and dst are the source and destination IP addresses and ports.
>   Tcpflags are some combination of **S (SYN)**, F (FIN), P (PUSH), R (RST),
>   U (URG), W (ECN CWR), E (ECN-Echo) or **'.' (ACK)**, or 'none' if no flags
>   are set

#### Why is the ACK flag represented by a period (`.`) instead of an `A`?

Some googling lead me to this:
https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/issues/319

Which implies the reason for not using an `A` is described here:
http://article.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/6383

But this link has been giving me a 522 error =/

Comment: [Internet Archive to the rescue](https://web.archive.org/web/20170618213921/http://article.gmane.org/gmane.network.tcpdump.devel/6383) — it's still not going to give you a satisfying answer, though.

Comment: @hobbs Good find!  And... you're right, I am still unsatisfied =(.  Going to leave the Q open to see if a better answer exists.  Either way, thanks for the link!